# Polymorphism without pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I was trying to create an abstract class and use it to determine the paying method of a purchase, using polymorphism. I tried some different things, but I can't still get it to work as I wanted. Here is the code:

```
class PaymentMethod {
    public:
        PaymentMethod() {}
        virtual std::string getPaymentMethod() = 0;
};

class PayWithMoney : public PaymentMethod {
    public:
        PayWithMoney() {}
        virtual std::string getPaymentMethod() {
            std::string paymentMethod = "Payed with Money"; 
            return paymentMethod;
        }
};

class PayWithDebitCard : public PaymentMethod {
    public:
        PayWithDebitCard() {}
        virtual std::string getPaymentMethod() {
            std::string paymentMethod = "Payed with Debit Card"; 
            return paymentMethod;
        }
};
```

And I have another class:

```
class Purchase {
    private:
        something
        PaymentMethod _paymentMethod;
    public:
        Purchase(something, const PaymentMethod& paymentMethod)
```

But I keep getting compiler error saying `cannot declare field ‘Purchase::_paymentMethod’ to be of abstract type ‘PaymentMethod’`.

I'm guessing I will have to use pointers instead right?

I thought I should try to avoid `new` and `delete` unless working with long-lived objects, but since `PaymentMethod` is an abstract class, I can't use it as a class member... Am I wrong?

Comment: Make `_paymentMethod` a reference or a pointer.  You still have to think about the lifecycle of the memory of the object, though.

Comment: Do you mean `PaymentMethod& _paymentMethod`?

Comment: Don't start your identifiers with _, like `_paymentMethod`. They are reserved for the implementation (that is, your compiler etc.) to use.

Comment: @Chowlett not true. only underscore followed by uppercase at the beginning or double underscore anywhere are.

Comment: @Tim. Hmm. True, only reserved in the global namespace. I sit corrected. Still probably a bad idea, though.

Comment: @Chowlett the rule is complicated enough that I would also suggest to avoid it, since that is much easier.

Comment: @msk:  That would work.  As I said, though, you still have to think about the lifecycle of the object, because even with a reference, you have to understand when the referent gets constructed and destructed.  Kerrek SB shows a much better method below, using `unique_ptr<>`, and I would strongly recommend you consider it.

Comment: @JoeZ I tried with references, but they can't be declared without inicialization, so I guess i'll do it with pointers, but here is my question:
Since I'm declaring a `PaymentMethod* _paymentMethod`, how should I give it as an argument in the constructor? `const PaymentMethod* x` ? If so, would would inicialize the class member _paymentMethod?

Comment: @msk:  You can use the initializer list in a constructor to initialize references.  ie.  `ctor( ref &a ) : member_a(a) { };`.  If you're using a pointer, you can initialize it similarly, only you have to pass a pointer into the constructor (either returned by `new` or by taking the address of an object).  If you take an address of an object _or_ pass it by reference, you need to be mindful of when it goes out of scope...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *should* try to avoid `new` and `delete`, that's absolutely correct.

Here's how:

```
#include <memory>       // for std::unique_ptr
#include <utility>      // for std::move

class Purchase
{
    Purchase(std::unique_ptr<PaymentMethod> payment_method)
    : payment_method_(std::move(payment_method))
    { }

    std::unique_ptr<PaymentMethod> payment_method_;

public:
    static Purchase MakeDebitCardPurchase()
    {
        return Purchase(std::make_unique<PayWithDebitCard>());
    }

    static Purchase MakeCashPurchase()
    {
        return Purchase(std::make_unique<PayWithCash>());
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
auto purchase = Purchase::MakeCashPurchase();
```

Note that `std::make_unique` doesn't exist yet, so you may instead have to say:

```
return Purchase(std::unique_ptr<PaymentMethod>(new PayWithCash));
```

This is the only time you have to say `new`, and even that will go away once `std::make_unique` is available in the standard library.

As an added benefit of this design, you can now easily add testing code, such as mock payment methods.

Comment: In this case I didn't really want to use smart pointers, as well as I shouldn't be using any kind of static things in my code

Comment: @msk Your choice is smart pointers or pointers, and smart pointers are smarter.  Do you have a religious objection to the `static` keyword, or do you have any other good reason to not use the keyword?

Comment: My teacher not liking the static keyword is my reason. Anyway, I tried with references, but I can't because it can't be declared without inicialization, so I will try it out with pointers

Comment: @msk: The private constructor and static factory functions are just one way of doing it. You can make the constructor public if you prefer and pass the payment method in manually. It's a matter of how much you want to expose, and to whom.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `PaymentMethod _paymentMethod` from the purchase class, your `Purchase` function receives it anyway.

Another thing, since you pass a const reference to `Purchase`, all the functions that `Purchase` calls must be const:

```
virtual std::string getPaymentMethod() = 0;
```

-->

```
virtual std::string getPaymentMethod() const = 0;
```

Comment: I want to store the PaymentMethod, because I have a method to get it later, thats why I created it as a class member.

Comment: Then your options are pointer or reference. The latter mandates you set it in the constructor.